# c# web browser control clicking a button based in tittle

Tags: c#

I want to click on this button

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="size  11.0" data-value=" 11.0" data-modelsize="11_0" data-sfs="false" class="button"> 11.0</a>
```

Would i need to find the tittle or the class, using

```
HtmlElementCollection classButton = webBrowser1.Document.All;
foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton) 
{
    if (element.GetAttribute("className") == "button")
    {
        element.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

that doesn't work because the class button is used 12 times on the website and everyone is a different shoe size to be selected

Comment: What happens when you run that code?

Comment: I would guess you'd want `element.GetAttribute("class") == "button"`

Comment: it doesnt select anything because the class "button" contains 12 different buttons

Comment: You should really add that to the question. The fact that you're trying to distinguish one button  out of 12 is completely unclear (if that is in fact what you are doing now).

Comment: `if (element.GetAttribute("title") == "size  11.0")` ?

Comment: I added that to the question could i use the tittle="size 11.0" or data-value="11.0" to find that specific button